# How to convert and compare dates in spring mongodb data

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to retrieve records from mongodb collection after certain date but the date field is stored as a string in mongodb collection. The below query doesn't work well I guess because it does a string comparison. How can I convert the string date from mongo and then compare with input date.

```
`mongoOperations.find(query(where("lastUpdated").gte(inputTimeStamp).and("status").in("COMPLETED")), Cart.class);`
```

Comment: To compare both the database field type and the input date type must be the same. In this case either as `Date` objects _or_ strings.

Comment: Both lastUpdated and inputTimeStamp are strings but that doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: Please post a sample document showing the data field, and sample input date - you are trying to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me. This may not be the best way to do it because it has potential of sql injection but I made sure data is sanitized before it reaches here.

```
 String queryStr = "{\"$expr\": {\"$gte\": [{ \"$dateFromString\": { \"dateString\": \"$lastUpdated\",timezone:\"America/New_York\" }}, new Date(\"%s\") ]},status:{$in:[\"COMPLETED\"]}}";
   BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery(String.format(queryStr,timeStamp));
   return  mongoTemplate.find(query, Cart.class);
```